# Navbar is not working in my react project

Tags: navbar, show, reactstrap

[enter link description here][1]

This is my source file and please check why my navbar isn't working? It doen't even show navbar on browser.
[1]: https://github.com/supriya-123-sys/portfolio/tree/master/hello/src

Comment: Try to create a sandbox or post your code here

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the "color" attribute for Navbar ("dark" as an example):

```
<Navbar color={"dark"} ...>
  .
  .
  .
</Navbar>
```